# Type Error: $.idleLogout is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, types

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.idleLogout({
        logoutSeconds: 30,
        countdownSeconds: 25,
        logoutUrl: null
    });

    $(document).bind('UserActivity.idleLogout UserIdle.idleLogout IdleLogout.idleLogout CancelLogut.idleLogout IdleDialogUpdate.idleLogout', function(e) {
        console.log(e.type, e.namespace, e);
    });
});
```

I got above error while using this code

Comment: You haven't loaded the plugin file

Comment: $.idleLogout it is function defined on js file

Comment: Then you are using it before defining it

Comment: I have loaded those jquery plugins

Comment: Thank you Tushar. I forgot that